# Getting C++ Segmentation Fault error in recursive n-queen program

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion, segmentation-fault

Basically, I have to write a basic program that solves the n-queen problem, which I have done, but it throws a segmentation fault if I input any number >=11.

From what I have read online, this error is usually caused by faulty logic when dealing with memory, but I can't seem to figure out what I have done wrong.

```
void generateBoard(int board[],int column,int length,int count)
{
    if(column == 0 && board[0]<length)  //prevents outputting the results infinitely 
    {
        ++board[0];
        generateBoard(board, ++column, length, count);
    } 
    else 
    {
        bool lineNotFound = true;
        int row = board[column];
        while(lineNotFound && row < length)
        {
            ++row; //temporary value for a column value candidate
            lineNotFound = false;
            for(int i = 0; i < column && !lineNotFound; ++i)
            {
                if(board[i] == row || (board[i]+column-i) == row || (board[i]-column+i) == row) // check diagonal and horizontal
                {
                    lineNotFound = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    board[column] = row;
                }
            }
        }
        if(column == length-1 && !lineNotFound) // at last column and valid board
        {
            output(board,length,++count);
            generateBoard(board,column,length,count);
        }
        else if(!lineNotFound) // not at last column, but valid position found
        {
            generateBoard(board,++column,length,count);
        }
        else if(column != 0) //no valid columns, go back a step
        {
            board[column] = 0;
            generateBoard(board,--column,length,count);
        }
    }
}
```

I realize that is a big chunk of code, but I think it's necessary to post it all to get an idea of the problem.

Any ideas? :s

I'm new to programming c++, so I don't know where to start debugging this.

Comment: Can you please write the value of the parameters you use to call the function that causes the segmentation fault.

Comment: "I'm new to programming c++, so I don't know where to start debugging this." Start by running your program under a debugger! With that you can find out which line blows up. That should give some information to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: int board[boardSize];
fill(board, board+boardSize, 0); 
generateBoard(board,0, boardSize, 0); So, in this case generateBoard(board,0, 11,0);

Comment: Running your code I get a stack overflow exception, and then we are back to the answer by @littleadv (at least some of it) is it possible you are mistaking the stack overflow for a seg fault?

Comment: It's saying segmentation fault when I run it. If a stack overflow can throw a segmentation fault, then maybe that is the problem. I don't believe the recursion is going infinitely.

Comment: @ChantryCargill: Recursion doesn't need to be infinite to cause a stack overflow, just sufficient to fill the call stack.

Comment: @ChantryCargill what OS and compiler are you using?

Comment: Care to explain the logic behind your program? I'm used to much simpler Queen search programs... Programs that go up to n level of recursion, where n is the board size. But these programs are built around a very simple `for` cycle. Your program seems to be different.

Comment: I'm using more than one OS. Linux and Windows Vista and using codeblocks and g++ on shell. The general idea behind what I'm doing is I check if there are any possible choices on a column (comparing to previous columns). If there is and it's not the last column, I move up a column. If there is and it's the last column, I go back a column and check for more possibilities. If there isn't any possible choices (regardless of column), I backtrack and check for another match in that column. I do this until it's not possible to continue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start debugging at the beginning and then let it run till the segmentation fault. When the fault occurs - look at the stack. I would guess that you're exceeding your stack with the recursion - that's the main problem with recursion programs.

You can enlarge your stack and then the fault will occur not with input 11 but with some other number, but recursive programs will always crash on stack issues with the input large enough.

By the way - make sure your recursion is bounded, i.e.: at some point your function should exit without calling itself further. IMHO, this is better be done at the beginning (although its a matter of style and convenience), because then you'll see clearly the condition upon which the recursion ends and it will be easier to debug infinite recursions (which also cause seg faults because of stack exhaustion). In your case it is not immediately clear how the recursion ends, and I wouldn't be surprised that it doesn't for some inputs.

**clarification**

While on some systems you get a "Stack Overflow" error, on others you would get "Segmentation Fault" for the same thing. I'm guessing you're on one of the "others".

To show that, I just compiled and ran this code:

```
int foo(long a)
{
  return foo(a-1);
}


int main()
{
   return foo(9999999999L);
}
```

On my GCC/Ububtu machine. This program has infinite recursion, which ends up with "**segmentation fault**" crash.

You can convert any recursive algorithm into iterative. Instead of recursively calling the function with new variables, use the STL `std::stack` to push and pop them and run in a loop. Here the details : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/stack/

Comment: I was able to get a stack overflow on VC++ with board size 8 :-)

Comment: Maybe he should just use the heap instead of the stack?

Comment: @mydogisbox: Use the heap?! call heap instead of call stack? that sounds ... interesting :P

Comment: Thanks little. If I could upvote, I would. I'm getting segmentation faults on different board sizes depending on which system I run the code on, so it definitely seems to be a stack overflow. Is there anything I can do about it, other than simply optimizing my code?

Comment: If your algorithm requires you to recurse down to a level that causes a stack overflow, you need to have a look at the algorithm, or how you use it.

Comment: @littleadv, hmmm...spent the last few minutes playing with it constantly. I've never heard of a system that does that, but I guess it can happen.

Comment: @TommyA I'm not really sure what you're getting at, but allocating the board on the heap instead of the stack might help alleviate stack overflow problems.

Comment: @mydogisbox: so you actually think the 11 x sizeof(int) that he has allocated on the stack before entering the recursion is what is the reason for the stack overflow? How many times do you think `generateBoard` calls itself? I can tell you that the problem is not a small array of integers allocated outside the scope of the function.

Comment: @TommyA nevermind, for some reason I was thinking the array was copied with each call.  What he really needs is some tail-recursion...