# Is it possible for std::sort to lead to a bug?

Tags: c++, std

My Question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680193/sigsegv-within-stdsort-how-to-narrow-it-down) as I solved the problem, I wrote my own sorting algorithm (a simple insertion sort), and it works. I am quite surprised by this as I thought that the standard library is well-tested. Are there any known special cases in which `std::sort` might mess up?

Comment: If your comparator is not self-consistent, then you could run into trouble.

Comment: what do you mean by self-consistent?

Comment: If your comparator does not give a consistent answer when called with (a, b) and (b, a), you can run into trouble.  If (a, b) returns true, then (b, a) had better return false.

Comment: Note, too, that it is a mark of a tyro (newbie) to suggest there's a bug in a routine (template) used as extensively as `std::sort`.  It is almost infinitely more probable that the problem is in the way you are using `std::sort` than that you've managed to find a problem (bug) in it.

Comment: You have the error. I have been in your place before but I was always wrong :)..

Comment: Yes you are right, the topic-header wasn't good, i modified it to make the context clearer.

Comment: If you want to get an actual _fix_ for your problem, you need to post the code for your comparator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's highly unlikely that there are any known bugs in any of the common C++ standard library implementations of `std::sort`.  It's rigorously tested.

If you see a crash or incorrect results, it's almost certainly because you didn't adhere to the contract: either you passed in invalid arguments, or your comparator does not obey the requirements for a [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering) (irreflexivity, asymmetry, transitivity, and transitivity of equivalence).

Answer (score 1):

If your comparison function/object doesn't follow a strict weak ordering, or the thing you're sorting contains pointers that are no longer valid, either of those could cause it to break.

Comment: well my algorithm doesn't tolerate nullpointer either, so the only possibility could be the second scenario, but I am not sure what exactly is meant by 'self consistent'

Comment: @Sim: It shouldn't be possible that `a < b` and `b < a` are both true.